# prove the equation by generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

Im studying a book about stochastic processes and it is mentioned in the book that the equation below is true and we can obtain it by generating functions can anyone prove it. Thanks a lot.
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{2m}{m}p^m = (1 - 4p)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: Well, it *is* a generating function. What exactly does it mean to obtain it by generating functions?

Comment: Im eager to know how to prove the equation.

Comment: Leave it in the airing cupboard for up to an hour until it doubles in size.